# PHP undefined variable

Tags: php, function, variables, encryption

I got a piece of code from Internet to encrypt my data using TripleDES.

```
$key = "ThisIsTheKey"; // 24 bit Key
$iv = "fYfhHeDm"; // 8 bit IV
$bit_check = 8; // bit amount for diff algor.


//function to encrypt
function encrypt($text) {
    global $key,$iv,$bit_check;
    $text_num = str_split($text, $bit_check);
    $text_num = $bit_check - strlen($text_num[count($text_num) - 1]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $text_num; $i++) {
        $text = $text . chr($text_num);
    }
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, '', 'cbc', '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_generic($cipher, $text);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
    return base64_encode($decrypted);
}
```

The problem is even though I call the variables as global, in the top (where I declared the variables) show the variable are unused. As well as when I try to run this it gave an error. But when I declare the same variable set inside the function it works.

Comment: Before you start dealing with security - you need to learn php very basics. Seriously.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide the exact error message.

Comment: Quick guess: what if you prepend each variable outside the function with `global`?

Comment: @zerkms Sod it, just prepend every variable declaration in the entire project with `global` :-P

Comment: @DaveRandom: and that wouldn't make that code worse ;-)

Comment: Don't use global, use constants.

Comment: @Fry_95: These are not constants. They may change based on what you need from the encryption function.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Maybe but not on the example, but if they change I'm agree with your answer below (I'll up it).

Comment: @Axel Isouard: "why don't you post an answer instead of keeping arguing here and defending an answer that is not even yours" --- because I don't like giving a man a fish. And in this case it doesn't worth teaching how to fish.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As a general note, The use of global variables is highly not recommended. When I look at your function, I see it only needs `$text`, however, it actually needs `$text`, `$key`, `$iv`, and `$bit_check`.

Lets try not using globals:

```
$key = "ThisIsTheKey"; // 24 bit Key
$iv = "fYfhHeDm"; // 8 bit IV
$bit_check = 8; // bit amount for diff algor.


//function to encrypt
function encrypt($text, $key, $iv, $bit_check) {
    $text_num = str_split($text, $bit_check);
    $text_num = $bit_check - strlen($text_num[count($text_num) - 1]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $text_num; $i++) {
        $text = $text . chr($text_num);
    }
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, '', 'cbc', '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $key, $iv);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_generic($cipher, $text);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
    return base64_encode($decrypted);
}
```

And call it using

```
encrypt("Hello World!", $key, $iv, $bit_check);
```

---

Another solution involves the use of CONSTANTS, assuming the key, iv and bit_check will **never change throughout the entire execution time,** you can define them as constants, and they would be globally available throughout the entire application, and **will not be able to change**.

Like so:

```
const KEY = "ThisIsTheKey"; // 24 bit Key
const IV = "fYfhHeDm"; // 8 bit IV
const BIT_CHECK = 8; // bit amount for diff algor.


//function to encrypt
function encrypt($text) {
    $text_num = str_split($text, BIT_CHECK);
    $text_num = BIT_CHECK - strlen($text_num[count($text_num) - 1]);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $text_num; $i++) {
        $text = $text . chr($text_num);
    }
    $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_TRIPLEDES, '', 'cbc', '');
    mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, KEY, IV);
    $decrypted = mcrypt_generic($cipher, $text);
    mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
    return base64_encode($decrypted);
}
```

Comment: Was about to hit "Post" when I saw your answer. :)

Comment: This was there. But the problem is for every time I need to pass the all parameters whenever I call this function. So is there any way to simplify it.

Comment: @sumer: What's wrong with passing all parameters? If your function needs all of those to work, you should be passing it in. When you write a recepie for a cake, you write "You need flour, water and eggs", not "You need flour" and then hope the reader would understand water and eggs are needed too.

Comment: If "water and eggs" don't change for each call, use constants. :)

Comment: @Fry_95: Only if the cake needs to be encrypted using a different type of flour or eggs, than it's not suitable :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Ya. But think like this. I use the way as you said in 100 pages, it would be fine. If need to make a change in key, then I need to change it on all 100 pages. :@.

Comment: @sumer: If the key will remain the same throughout the entire execution and will never change, !@Fry_95's solution would be preferrable. I'll edit my answer to add that.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: with pleasure.